# How to catch events (string plucked) from a Guitar Tab?

Tags: python, events, triggers, midi, guitar

I m writing to you to have advice on a methodology to achieve a specific musical purpose.

I have a project where I would like to robotize and automatize the “right hand” of a guitarist, which means, plucking the strings  not with the hand, but with plectrums, attached to step motors ( 6 plectrums attached to 6 step motors, each one over each string). Then I would still use my own left hand to play on the neck.

To do this, I do not want to hard-code it, but instead create a flexible algorithm, which means that I would like to first, create the guitar tab in an editor, like TuxGuitar, and then get events every time a string is plucked, and trigger the corresponding motor (in python, C++ ..).

The issue is I am struggling finding a right way to do so. First I found PyGuitarPro, but, from my understanding, it only reads and manipulates files, but there is no notion of time and playback. Then I was thinking of exporting the Tab from TuxGuitar into midi and then using another lib to read those event, but by exporting into midi, I lose the information of the guitar tab, which tells me which string is plucked ( as a single note can be played on different strings on the guitar).

Would you have a good starting point to achieve this?

Thanks!

Antoine

Comment: Convert in midi but attribute one midi note to one motor. With pyGuitarPro modify your track to set all the note on the first string to the midi note 50 for example.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, I ll try it!